# Connecting LiFePo4 in series?

Tags: power, batteries, solar-charge-controller

I am looking for 3 LifePo4 batteries for a project, since they are quite stable when compared to Li-po/Li-ion. I have found [this battery](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/speciality-size-rechargeable-batteries/8183018) that fulfils the max amp draw requirements. I need three in series, to create a nominal voltage of 9V for a Genasun lithium MPPT. The problem is, that in the data sheet it says: "do not solder directly to the battery" and "do not join cells". Is this just legal stuff to cover their back in the event I somehow make it explode and injure myself? Or should I continue searching?

Comment: They may be worried that by "joining" cells the charging and balancing wouldn't be done properly.  However, if the datasheet says not to do it, I wouldn't do it with something as dangerous as a lithium battery.  You could maybe try to contact the companies tech support to ask for clarification.

Comment: *Probably* the former.

Comment: Could get a small spot-welder and some tin/nickel strips, would recommend that over soldering.  YouTube is littered with reviews of cheap spot-welders.

Comment: Perhaps a more likely answer: perhaps they say not to, because it won't work well, because of the material the battery is made of. Soldering a big metal can is going to take a lot of heat that is liable to damage the battery.